# Netflix Streaming Error Code: F7121-1331-P7 In Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox 50.1.0

Tags: 16.04, firefox, streaming, netflix

I recently was able to starting watching Netflix natively on Ubuntu 16.04 after Firefox 49 brought support for Widevine CDM [late last year](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/firefox-49-linux-netflix-google-widevine-cdm). All I had to do was spoof my user agent to say I'm using Firefox on Windows using the User Agent Switcher add-on and it worked seamlessly.

However, now anytime I attempt to stream anything on Netflix, the following message and error code are displayed:

```
Whoops, something went wrong...
Unexpected Error
There was an unexpected error. Please reload the page and try again.
Error Code: F7121-1331-P7
```

If I revert to my default user agent, I'm taken to the "[Netflix system requirements for HTML5 Player and Silverlight](https://help.netflix.com/en/node/23742)" page.

I haven't been able to find any information about this error code online and I'm curious if anyone else has been experiencing this issue and if it is unique to Ubuntu. Currently running Firefox 50.1.0.

Comment: I've experienced the same error, and no, it does not appear to be unique to Ubuntu, as there is a thread in the Arch Linux forums about it as well. The solution (at least for now) seems to be to set the user agent string to the Linux version of Chrome 55.0 (64-bit).

Comment: Well, in my case, the solution of Jordan doesn't work, Netflix works but when you want to reproduce a film or something it doesn't load.
It's like the browser is trying to load the video but it can't.

Comment: PC_LOAD_LETTER, is your system 32 or 64 bit? My 32 bit systems worked with FF 49, but do not work with FF 50.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04LTS 64-bit. Also, when I asked "is it unique to Ubuntu" what I really meant was... is it unique to Linux?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by using the following user agent string from the latest version of Chrome for Linux: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"

Comment: @PC_LOAD_LETTER If you have an answer to this question, please write it as an answer (yes, even if it's your own question).

Comment: I would have, if I could. A previous answer was removed for being low-quality and now only those with "10 reputation" can answer this question. Hence why I wrote my answer as a comment and changed the title to "[SOLVED]." It's all I can do as a new user.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You can always answer your own question. This is a Q&A site. We show that a question has been answered or a problem solved with an accepted answer in the answer space. We don't use the word 'solved'. :)

Comment: Fine. If you'd rather have people visiting this post thinking it is still unanswered, than to put "[SOLVED]" in the title that is 100% on you. Once again, I am NOT able answer my own question! So answer it yourself if you insist on removing "[SOLVED]" from the title, because I can't.

Comment: "protected by Community♦ Jan 19 at 3:22

Thank you for your interest in this question. Because it has attracted low-quality or spam answers that had to be removed, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

Would you like to answer one of these unanswered questions instead?"

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for your response! Your fix solved my problem. Can you please post your comment as an "answer," so I can mark this question as answered. Thanks!